# Prevent spamming a button that triggers an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two buttons that add or substract a quantity of a product and update the price etc on a digital receipt using ajax. The problem is when a user spams the button the quantity does not align with the quantity in the input box.

For example if I click really fast, the input box can have a quantity value of 10 and the receipt will say 8.

How can I prevent that?

I was thinking to only make the buttons trigger the function once the ajax call is finished.

This is my code:

```
$(".formatenkeuze .plusmin").on("click", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection, stepPosition) {
  if($('#aantalinput').val() > 0) {
    $('.formateninput').removeClass('alertmessage');
    $('.controlemelding').hide();

    var form_data = $("#formsid form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data:({form_data: form_data}),
      success:function(data){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $( "#ajaxresult" ).empty().append( obj[0].productinfo );
        $('#prijsonder').empty().append($('#prijs').html());
      }
    });

  } else{
    $('.formateninput').addClass('alertmessage');
    $('.controlemelding').css('display','flex');
  }
});
```

Maybe set a variable to `false` on click and only set it to `true` when an ajax call is complete and only make the function trigger when the variable is set to `true`?

Comment: Having some sort of `shouldSubmit` variable would be the correct way, but I would also consider having some sort of indication to the user that the submit is happening (disable the button, show a loader, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the button is a `<input type="button">` or `<button>` element then you can simply disable it before sending the AJAX request and enable it again when the call completes. Try this:

```js
$(".formatenkeuze .plusmin").on("click", function(e) {
  var $button = $(this).prop('disabled', true), // disable here
    $formateninput = $('.formateninput'),
    $controlemelding = $('.controlemelding');

  if ($('#aantalinput').val() > 0) {
    $formateninput.removeClass('alertmessage');
    $controlemelding.hide();

    var form_data = $("#formsid form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data: { form_data: form_data },
      success: function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#ajaxresult").html(obj[0].productinfo);
        $('#prijsonder').html($('#prijs').html());
      },
      complete: function() {
        $button.prop('disabled', false); // enable here
      }
    });
  } else {
    $formateninput.addClass('alertmessage');
    $controlemelding.css('display', 'flex');
  }
});
```

Comment: They are `<button>` elements yes so this worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Quite the dupe though

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** the timeout represents your ajax call

You can hide the button after clicking and display it again once the ajax success handler executes:

```js
$('#btn').click(() => {
  $('#btn').hide();
  // this is your ajax call mocked by a setTimeout
  setTimeout(() => {
    // this is the success handler
    $('#btn').show()
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: the timeout is simply a "mock" request omg....of course this should not be implemented as timeout hence the comments in the code

Comment: @messerbill apologies - my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the button when the button is pressed and enabling the button again after the ajax call has completed will prevent users from spam clicking your button.

You can disable/enable your button with jQuery like this:

```
$(this).attr('disabled', true)
```

Comment: .prop is likely a better call

Answer (score 0):

Just simply disable it the moment you click it.

```js
$("#plus").on("click", function(params) {
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');;
  $('#spinner').css({
    display: 'block'
  });
  //do ajax 
  //error -> handle error  ->  $('#spinner').css({display: 'none'}); ->  $(this).disable(false);
  //success -> show success message  $('#spinner').css({display: 'none'}); ->  $(this).attr('disabled','false');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus">Plus</button>
<span id="spinner" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></span>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not actually run

Comment: It does now, I didn't include jquery library, but it isn't supposed to fully run, it was just a description on how this problem could be solved. As you can see I just did descriptive process of the ajax request and what to do in situations of error and success. This is one way for the OP to resolve his problem, he just needs to apply it to his own case.

Comment: Sure. Just remove the top line when creating a snippet that does not actually run. You have not included Font Awesome either

Comment: You're right, my bad.